# How to reset a Zend rememberMe function on each automatic login?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using a remember me checkbox implemented with a Zend rememberMe function for automatic login. I have written this condition inside the controller for login, but I want it to reset to 7 days on each automatic login (as long as the current login is an automatic one).

$seconds = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7; // 7 days
Zend_Session::rememberMe($seconds);

Is there a default zend function to update the cookie during each access. Btw, I'm new to coding. Hope someone can help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't want to set the cookie using `Zend_Session::rememberMe()` on each access.  The reason for this is simply because each call to `rememberMe()` causes a new session id to be generated and the cookie is replaced by one with a new id.  Data from the old session is copied to the new one and the old session is deleted.

Although no real harm would come out of this, there is overhead involved in doing this on each request.  According to Zend, it is best practice to call this after the session has been started.

Also, if you did this unconditionally on each request, the only way you can differentiate between an automatic login after extended time and casual browsing would be to store the timestamp in the session and check it at the beginning of each request and set a time limit to determine a person as having gone away.

Instead, you could do this when a returning visitor goes to your login page to log in; you could then redirect them and they would be logged in without authenticating.

Or, if you want to update the session cookie periodically, you could call `rememberMe()` in your `Bootstrap.php` file after you have started the session.  If you start the session from a plugin, or directly in the controllers, you should put the remember me call there after the session starts, and do it every so often (at your discretion).

See [session_regenerate_id()](http://php.net/session_regenerate_id) which gets called when you call `Zend_Session::rememberMe()` and [Zend Framework - Session Identifiers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.global_session_management.html#zend.session.global_session_management.session_identifiers), as well as the following section on Session Hijacking and Fixation.

Comment: zend docs says to call rememberMe before starting the session "Use Zend_Session::rememberMe() before a session is started to control the length of time before a persisted session cookie expires. "

Comment: Correct, they do say to call it before a session is started to control the expiration time of the cookie.  To clarify in this case, since `rememberMe()` calls `Zend_Sesssion::regenerateId()` as well, the best practice for calling `regenerateId()` is to call it after the session has been started.  In the Qu, he is wanting to do this frequently so I'd do it after the session was started in order to set a new cookie with the new ID after it has resumed the previous question.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use Zend_session to do that. Use cookies for make remember me.